# It didn't work when I post a file with requests.post

Tags: python, request

this is my code:

```
params = {
    "zipFile":"123456.zip",
    "projectName" : "test"
    }

dispatch = r.post("http://biqatest.baidu.com/dispatch/project/upload",files = params)
```

As you can see,it's a post request.

but the reponse is:

```
405
>Request method 'GET' not supported
```

It's so strange,why?

Comment: shouldn't be `data=params`, instead of `files`?

Comment: What is `r`? Can you show us how you create it/where it comes from?

Comment: r = requests.session()

Comment: based on the documentation example here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file it seems like you should define your file and open and should be passed as files, but then the projectname: test part, shouldn't that be passed as data?

Answer (score 0):

```
file = {'file': open('yourzipfile.zip', 'rb')}
data = {'projectName': 'test'}
dispatch = r.post("http://biqatest.baidu.com/dispatch/project/upload",files=file, data=data)
```

Comment: your suggestion is right. I make a mistake at 
    file = {'file': open('yourzipfile.zip', 'rb')}
but it didn't work either.
I think may be there is a mistake on server.